# java.io.InvalidClassException while deserializing object after some modification in a java class

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

Why failed to deserialized however I have serialized this Container class using `serialVersionUID = 75264711556228L;`

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 75264711556228L;
    public boolean isFromLocalCollect=false;
    public boolean isFromLocalCollect=false;
    public void setFromLocalCollect(boolean isFromLocalCollect) {
        this.isFromLocalCollect=isFromLocalCollect;
    }
    public boolean getFromLocalCollect() {
        return this.isFromLocalCollect;
    }
}
```

now i have added one more setter and getter method in Container class after serialized with name container.ser like:

```
public class Container implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 75264711556228L;
    public boolean isFromLocalCollect=false;
    public boolean isFromLocalCollect=false;
    public void setFromLocalCollect(boolean isFromLocalCollect) {
        this.isFromLocalCollect=isFromLocalCollect;
    }
    public boolean getFromLocalCollect() {
        return this.isFromLocalCollect;
    }
    public boolean isFromLocalCollect2=false;
    public void setFromLocalCollect2(boolean isFromLocalCollect2) {
        this.isFromLocalCollect2=isFromLocalCollect2;
    }
    public boolean getFromLocalCollect2() {
        return this.isFromLocalCollect2;
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to deserialize the object using project name changed but failed to deserialized and error i got like:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: cvb.db.PbDb; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -444070985558173412, local class serialVersionUID = 4350771162641935418
```

Answer (score 3):

When you serialized the object you used a version of the `Container.class` differents from the `Container.class` used to deserialize it.

**You need to use always the same .class** to be sure that the operation of serialization deserialization will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what i did that i just used this static final serialVersionUID variable in cvb.db.PbDb class like:

**private static final long serialVersionUID = 75264711556227L;**

and in Container class were already declared serialVersionUID explicitly.
After that i am serializing and deserializing with different application context path so exception has gone away and now it's working fine for me.